# How to pass the returned value of SELECT statement to DELETE query in stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have the requirement to delete the child data's(foreign key constraints mapped) of some tables in DB. So, actually, i wanna to pass the value of returned SELECT query into the DELETE statement.

Following is the Stored Procedure i have created,pls help me to know about this and also give some examples to delete the child rows from table.

```
delimiter //
create procedure deleteCustomerDeps(in emailAddr varchar(50)) 
begin 
select customer_id into custId
from customer
where customer_id=emailAddr;
set @custoId=custId;
delete from customer where customer_id='@custoId';
prepare stmt from @custoId;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
end //
delimiter ;
```

TIA....

Comment: You didn't mentioned the child table(s): name, schema, how related

Comment: Mr.Peter,just i write the sample procedure. It's not my complete proc.Can you show me the example using child table for the following scenario, let's say there is a customer table and it's dependent tables are order_details. I want to delete the order processed for the customer. You can see in my sample procedure, i will the email address as a parameter, then i will retrieve the customer id to pass into the orders table to delete. So, like this scenario i wanna to delete the child tables.Pls help me know about this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you have the following schema

```
CREATE TABLE customers
(
  customer_id INT, 
  customer_email VARCHAR(17),
  PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
);
CREATE TABLE child_table
(
  child_id INT,
  customer_id INT, 
  value INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (child_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers (customer_id)
);
```

Now to delete all child records knowing an email of the customer you can use multi-table delete syntax

```
CREATE PROCEDURE deleteCustomerData(IN emailAddr VARCHAR(50)) 
  DELETE t
    FROM child_table t JOIN customers c 
      ON t.customer_id = c.customer_id
   WHERE c.customer_email = emailAddr;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbadc/1)** demo

---

> *...but if i want to pass the returned value of SELECT stmt to DELETE...*

That is exactly what you're doing in above mentioned example. But you can always rewrite it this way

```
DELETE t
  FROM child_table t JOIN 
(
  SELECT customer_id 
    FROM customers JOIN ...
   WHERE customer_email = emailAddr
     AND ...
) c
    ON t.customer_id = c.customer_id
```

or

```
DELETE 
  FROM child_table 
 WHERE customer_id IN 
(
  SELECT customer_id 
    FROM customers JOIN ...
   WHERE customer_email = emailAddr
     AND ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Mr.Peter.It will work but if i want to pass the returned value of SELECT stmt to DELETE queries statements.What should i want to do?.Please see my stored procedure in the post.

Comment: See updated answer. Where are multiple ways to do this and `JOIN` is the best one. Your procedure code is syntactically incorrect and doesn't make much sense especially the usage of prepared statements.

Comment: Yup..I know that proc is syntactically incorrect...thanks for your help Mr.Peter.....

Comment: I am looking for this only and also i want to know, how to pass the returned value of SELECT query into DELETE statement. Do you have any idea about this scenario?